Winui ComboBox in a control default initial index not working correctly
I am creating a Usercontrol that has a Combobox in it.
<UserControl>
...

        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ReasonComboBox"
                  PlaceholderText="{x:Bind ComboBoxPlaceHolderLabel, Mode=OneWay}"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSource}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="{x:Bind DisplayMemberPath, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  SelectedIndex="{x:Bind SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

</UserControl>

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value);
    }

    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedIndex",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(ComboBoxInput),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedIndexPropertyChanged)));

Everything works fine if the default initial index is -1. But if we set the default inital index to another value, eg:3, the combobox will always end up have both index 0 and index 3 selected. When debugging, it shows that item 3 is selected, but the UI shows item 0 selected as well and if you try clicking on item 0, the PropertyChanged event does not get called, so now there is there way to select item 0 at all.
If it's just a native comboBox, changing the initial index works correctly. This error only occurs if we try to embed the ComboBox within a user control.

I can't reproduce your issue. How are you '3' as the initial index? How are you checking that SelectedIndex is 3 when the selected item is 0?

during debugging. I looked at the data state of the combobox object. The object says selectedIndex is 3, but in my dropdown I will have both item 0 and item 3 highlighted as selected.

Can you share code? How are you setting '3' as the initial index?

I have uploaded sample code here. https://github.com/karmelcorn/winuicombobox Thank you for your help.

I took a look at your repo and here's the minimal reproducible code of your issue:
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="2">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
</ComboBox>

which renders:

According to the docs:

ComboBox uses a CarouselPanel as its ItemsPanel. Using a different panel as the ItemsPanel is not supported and might result in undesired behavior.

So not changing the ItemsPanel fixes your issue.

Ah! Thank you! But unfortunately on the touchscreen, the default CarouselPanel was behaving like an infinite scroll-list so we needed to customize the ItemsPanel for our case :(.

I can't repro that infinite scroll on my laptop (touch screen), but I suggest you should follow the docs here.

Ah took me a while to recollect and reproduce, but the infinite scroll happens when the selection list is too long (in relation to the app screen space) on a touch screen. I will dig into the docs to see if I can find out more. Thank you!!
